# Why are Cu2+ ions blue?

Tags: ions, color

I figured that it is probably having to do with the wavelengths of visible light that are absorbed and transmitted by the ions, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Your assumption about the absorption of light at different wavelengths is on the right track